# Can you recover deleted YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to see deleted YouTube videos? Some kind of archival or some such? There were some controversial videos that the creator felt necessary to remove or made private but it would be nice if the Internet can still remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

Unless you (or someone) has backed up the video prior to its deletion it is, for all intents and purposes, gone for good.

It's possible that YouTube might have the videos stored on their servers for a period of time before they're actually deleted, but either way that won't do you much good. They don't provide users access to deleted videos--maybe they'd respond to a subpoena or warrant if law enforcement wanted access to a recently deleted video, but a regular user is out of luck.

Comment: Hmm, aren't there services that would cache videos prior to removal? Like Google Cache, or archive.org, or perhaps other website that clone Youtube content?

Comment: That's an interesting idea, and there may be something like that out there. I personally have not heard of any. If you (or anyone) finds one that works, it would be worth posting as a new answer.

Comment: I did find this: https://archive.org/details/movies , but when I was looking a for a specific movie that went down, I couldn't find it. But others maybe can...

Comment: You can use www.recovermy.video to recover at least the titles of deleted/private videos on your YouTube playlist